# Inserting a text into a file, like adding an array element

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh

I have a JavaScript **file** like below.

**Me.dat**

```
var fruit = [
 "Apple",
 "Mango",
 "Orange"
];

var players = [
 "Sachin",
 "Dhoni",
 "Kapil Dev"
];
```

---

I would need to dynamically add an element to any of these array.(in the file actually).

Based on a job status, I would insert into the corresponding array.

Say for example,

```
addMe "Grapes" "fruits"
```

Would create a file,

```
var fruit = [
 "Apple",
 "Mango",
 "Orange",
 "Grapes" ---------Added newly!!!
];

var players = [
 "Sachin",
 "Dhoni",
 "Kapil Dev"
];
```

So, I have to insert the text "Grapes" in the 5th line of the file.

---

This is what I have now..

**My Script:**

```
SEARCHTERM="fruits";
TO_BE_ADDED="Grapes";
#take the start line number and end linenumer of the array..
startlinenum=`grep -n $SEARCHTERM me.dat | cut -d ":" -f1 | head -1`;
endlinenum=`tail +$startlinenum me.dat | grep -n "]" | head -1 | cut -d ":" -f1`;
endlinenum=`expr $startlinenum + $endlinenum - 2`;

echo "\"$TO_BE_ADDED\"" > to_be_added.dat;

echo "ENd line is : ${endlinenum}";

sed "${endlinenum}r to_be_added.dat" me.dat
```

---

I got the **output** as,

```
var fruits = [
 "Apple",
 "Mango",
 "Orange" ------ How would I remove this Comma ? :(
"Grapes" ------ Added Correctly....
];
```

---

Am I doing a right thing here? Or is there a simpler way around?

Any help please. How would I remove the comma like I mentioned in previous snippet.

Comment: No, you're going about it all wrong. The UNIX shell is simply an environment from which to call UNIX tools with a language to sequence those calls. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. So scrap all the shell/sed/grep stuff and just call awk,

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I jus tried with whatever I know of. Rarely I get some work like this. And this one interested me to try it myself..(Job satisfaction :)) Still many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will mangle your formatting (replacing all whitespace within a modified record with a single space), but perhaps this is helpful:

```
$ TOBEADDED=banana
$ SEARCHTERM=fruit
$ awk '/var '$SEARCHTERM'/{$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)", \"'$TOBEADDED'\""}1' RS= Me.dat
var fruit = [ "Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "banana" ];
var players = [
        "Sachin",
        "Dhoni",
        "Kapil Dev"
];
```

It's fairly easy to modify the solution to put the formatting back in, but doing so obscures the solution, so I'll leave it as is.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry , I do get `awk`  compilation error. Am not a pro with awk.

Comment: Not sure about your compilation error.  I'll edit the answer with a full transcript showing usage.

Comment: For some reasons my awk version in `UNIX` gave me `awk:bail out.. ` error. But it worked perfectly with `gawk` version in my windows  PC. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WIth GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ gawk -v add="Grapes" -v tgt="fruit" -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" -v FS="\n" '
  $1~" "tgt" "{$0=gensub(/(([ \t]+)"[^"]+")(\n];)/,"\\1,\n\\2\""add"\"\\3","")}1
' Me.dat
var fruit = [
 "Apple",
 "Mango",
 "Orange",
 "Grapes"
];

var players = [
 "Sachin",
 "Dhoni",
 "Kapil Dev"
];
```